# Creating a ppt or pptx blob from byteArray in typescript/angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, blob

I need to convert my byteArray response into ppt Blob Object to create a .ppt/.pptx file in Angular 2. I am able to convert to image and pdf formats. But I need specifically for ppt and pptx  formats.

var blob = new Blob(resp, {type: 'application/pdf'});

AS above, what is the type to be given for ppt or pptx conversion?

Please mention if I need to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for *Microsoft PowerPoint* **MIME Types**:

- **.ppt** (proprietary format before PowerPoint 2007)

`application/vnd.ms-powerpoint`

- **.pptx** (open format since PowerPoint 2007)

`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation`